# Find average revenue by each subcategory of top 5 categories in terms of quantity sold in vba sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two data set `prod_cat_info` and `Transactions` with two common fields for product category and sub category. I am trying to get average revenue by each subcategory of top 5 category in terms of quantity sold. I tried it from below query in which where clause is not working.

```
SELECT prod_cat_info.prod_subcat, AVG(Transactions.total_amt)
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN
    prod_cat_info
    ON Transactions.prod_cat_code = prod_cat_info.prod_cat_code AND
        Transactions.prod_subcat_code = prod_cat_info.prod_sub_cat_code
GROUP BY prod_cat_info.prod_subcat
WHERE Transactions.prod_cat_code IN (
    SELECT TOP 5 Transactions.prod_cat_code
    FROM Transactions
    GROUP BY Transactions.prod_cat_code
    ORDER BY SUM(Transactions.Qty) DESC
    )
GROUP BY prod_cat_info.prod_subcat
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, make some attempt to format your query.

Comment: Access database

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a subquery at all.  Just use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP (5) pci.prod_subcat, AVG(t.total_amt)
FROM Transactions t INNER JOIN
     prod_cat_info pci
     ON t.prod_cat_code = pci.prod_cat_code AND
        t.prod_subcat_code = pci.prod_sub_cat_code
GROUP BY pci.prod_subcat 
ORDER BY SUM(t.qty DESC);
```

EDIT:

In MS Access and for the clarified question:

```
SELECT pci.prod_cat_code, pci.prod_subcat, AVG(t.total_amt)
FROM Transactions as t INNER JOIN
     prod_cat_info as pci
     ON t.prod_cat_code = pci.prod_cat_code AND
        t.prod_subcat_code = pci.prod_sub_cat_code
WHERE pci.prod_cat_code IN (
          SELECT TOP 5 t.prod_cat_code
          FROM Transactions as t
          GROUP BY t.prod_cat_code
          ORDER BY t.qty DESC
         )
GROUP BY pci.prod_cat_code, pci.prod_subcat;
```

Comment: I need all subcategories for top 5 category